# Easy to way to time Indy connect and receive times?

Tags: delphi, indy

Is there an easy way to get the time it took Indy to connect, and the time it took to receive data, in a `TIdHTTP.Get()` or `TIdHTTP.Put()` operation?

EDIT:
I want to get statistics to determine which timeouts are best to use for the `ReceiveTimeout` and `ConnectTimeOut` properties.

Comment: Start a TStopWatch when you begin a request and stop it when the request is done. See the doc: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch. Looks so easy that I surely missed something in your question...

Comment: yes, I could also do that using GetTIckCount or something. :-)
I need to find to spot to measure the CONNECT time - whereas getting the whole connect+send+receive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For timing a connect, you can use the `OnStatus(hsConnecting)` and `OnStatus(hsConnected)`/`OnConnected` events.  Note that if a URL involves a hostname (which is the usual case), there is also an `OnStatus(hsResolving)` event that precedes the `OnStatus(hsConnecting)` event.  However, DNS resolution does not play into `ConnectTimeout` handling at this time.

For timing the receive, that is a bit trickier, since there are no events for detecting the end of sending a request, or the beginning/ending of reading a response <sup>1</sup>.  And also that a given HTTP request may involve multiple steps (redirects, authentication, etc), which may also involve multiple disconnects/re-connects since HTTP is a stateless protocol not dependent on a persistent connection, like most other protocols are.  So, about the only way I can think of accomplishing this is to attach an `Intercept` component to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property and then manually parse the HTTP messages as they are being exchanged.

- <sup>1</sup> Actually, that is not *entirely* true.  There is a `TIdHTTP.OnHeadersAvailable` event, which is fired after the HTTP response headers have been read, and before the HTTP response body is read, at least.  So, if you don't care about the timing of the headers, you can use that event to start timing the receiving of the body data, at least.  And then stop the timing when `Get()`/`Post()` exits.  For each multi-step that requires `TIdHTTP` to repeat a request, you should get a new `OnHeadersAvailable` event, which you can use to reset your timer.  That way, you end up with the time of the final response only.

However, note that `ReceiveTimeout` is a *per-byte* timeout, so an alternative might be to use a custom `TStream` (or Indy's `TIdEventStream`) to receive the HTTP response data into, and then you can time the durations between individual writes to that stream by overwriting its `Write()` method (or using the `OnWrite` event).

Comment: yes, the events should be enough for the primary reason (to get the values for the timeout properties), but I might even look into the parsing of the Interceptor. Great Input, thx!